# Override Fluent Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a mapping assembly called MyApp.Mapping.dll which maps lots of entities and I also have the following mapping:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
//(...)
HasManyToMany(p => p.Roles).Not.LazyLoad()
//(...)
```

The Roles association is mapped as not lazyload for whatever reason.

For a ver specific reason I want to Lazy map this association and for what I have researched, it is not possible to fetch a eager mapped association as Lazy in a Criteria.

So the question is:

**Can I create another mapping class in another assembly that overrides UserMap mapping so that I can reuse MyApp.Mappings.dll for other entities?**

Answer (score 0):

you can build up the configuration object and then

```
var roles = config
    .GetClassMapping(typeof(User))
    .GetProperty("Roles");

roles.IsLazy = false;

config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Hope that helps